# Laravel 5.7 Validate with form field different from model attribute

Tags: laravel

I am having trouble running the laravel validation on the following situation.

I have a form where the user is signing up himself and his company (empresa).

Both the user and the empresa have the 'documento' attribute, so on the form I called it 'cpf' for the persons document and 'documento_corp' for the company document.

The thing is i need to check wheter these are already registered.

I tried the following but it gives me

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'documento_corp' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `empresas` where `documento_corp` = 29242509000122 and (`documento` = 29242509000122))

```
return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10', new Telefone],
        'cpf' => ['required', 'string', 'min:11', new Cpf],

        'name_corp' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email_corp' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
        'phone_corp' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10', new Telefone],
        'documento_corp' => ['required', 'string', 'min:11', Rule::unique('empresas')->where(function($query) use ($data) {
            return $query->where('documento', $data['documento_corp']);
        }), new CpfOuCnpj],
        'cep_corp' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
        'rua_corp' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5'],
        'uf_corp' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:2'],
        'bairro_corp' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5'],
        'cidade_corp' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2'],
    ]);
```

How do i do this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do `unique:empresas,documento`?

The syntax is: *unique:table,column,except,idColumn*

Comment: That did it. Thanks.